# Is it possible to edit the contents of a <script type="text/template"> with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's an example of what I'm trying to edit:

```
<script id="login-popup" type="text/template"> 
  <h3 id="cover-msg" class="modal-title">You need to login to do that.</h3>`
</script>
```

I would like to add: `class="title"` to the h3 tag. This is being done via a chrome extension, so I can't control the HTML that is rendered.

Here's the caveat: I can't assume that the template will always be the same, so I can't just replace or edit the entire thing. I need to be able to select certain elements within the text and only add things as needed.

The problem I'm having is that the template *seems* to just be plain text. So I can't select it with something like `#login-popup #cover-msg`. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Is it possible to do this with JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: $("#cover-msg").addClass('title'), or are you trying to change the type of the script? I think you can do $("#login-popup").attr('type','text/sometemplatevariable')

Comment: @BryanMudge The tag isn't rendered as a part of the DOM because it's in a script tag.

Comment: You'll have to get the `innerHTML` of the script block, parse it, do whatever you need to do, and then set the `innerHTML` from the result.

Comment: you could use a template library like trimpath, handlebars, etc. to render the text to html and then manipulate it as you wish

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can follow this type of procedure which gets the text out of the script tag, inserts it into a DOM element so you can use DOM manipulation on it, then gets the resulting HTML out of that DOM element.  This allows you to avoid any manual parsing of the HTML text yourself:

```
var t = document.getElementById("login-popup");
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = t.innerHTML;
$(div).find("h3").addClass("title");
t.innerHTML = div.innerHTML;
```

It follows this process:

1. Get the innerHTML from the script tag
2. Create a temporary div
3. Puts the HTML into the temporary div where you can then treat it as DOM elements
4. Using DOM query, find the `<h3>`
5. Adds the class to it
6. Get the HTML back out of the temporary div
7. Puts the HTML back into the script tag as the modified version of the template.

It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/mqnf1mmp/.

Comment: Works perfect, thanks. Just a quick question. Why does it not work when I do var t = $("#login-popup"); ?

Comment: @Smac - When you do `var t = $("#login-popup");`, `t` is a jQuery object, not a DOM object so that would work only if you converted other methods in the code to jQuery methods.